# Facebook Auth2 for Google Aps Script

Tags: facebook-graph-api, google-apps-script

I am trying to connect to Facebook API using [this project](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/apps-script-oauth2). But the Authentication shows an error:

> Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's
>   domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and subdomains of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings.

I added the following domains but it still not working

- datastudio.google.com
- script.google.com
- google.com

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Yes I found it )).
The problem was that I used the name of my callback function authCallback as a "usercallback" part of redirect URI. So for me the redirect URI was

> https://script.google.com/macros/d/{SCRIPT ID}/authCallback

That is a mistake.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: could you please elaborate on what exactly you did? I'm facing the same issue